# Force Commit to GX Server

Tags: genexus

I have a few objects that need to be Committed to GXServer but for some reason I am getting a failure.  The message is something like:

'Commit failed: At least Environment 'Java Environment' was modified in GeneXus Server since your last update.  Please Update Knowledge Base and retry.'

When I go to the Update Tab in GXS for this KB it is empty - I am in sync.  It seems like I am stuck - the Commit side says Update but the Update side says I am in sync.

I have been able to Commit all of the objects except the one listed in this error.  In my case, I am sure I have the latest version of the object, so I need to know how to force this object to GXS.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to share with the Community the answer I received from Support as it solved the problem.  If you run into this and have questions you can ask Support and they can give you more official details.  This is my take on the situation.

If you know the object in the error should be Committed, you can make a change to a file in your running GX version to 'force' the Commit.  Here are the steps I followed:

- You should be able to Commit all objects except the one in question.  It is best IMO to commit all objects normally and only have the object in error listed.
- Close GX
- In Windows Explorer find the GeneXus installation folder (something like C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus16U5)
- Open the file GeneXus.exe.config for editing ( you may need 'Run as Administrator')
- Search for `</appSettings>`
- Above this line, add a line with this information

  - `<add key="ForceCommit" value="true"/>`
- Save your changes
- Open KB and Commit the object in question
- Once the object is committed, close GX and remove the line from the config file so you are not forcing future objects up.

This force process should NOT be used unless you are in this situation, and it should not be a normal occurrence.

Also, make sure you change the correct file.  One time I edited a file with a similar name by mistake (even the contents looked similar), and it did not work.

The last time I performed this was in GX 16 U5.  I do not know what the original issue was that caused the conflict, but this was the way I was given to force the Commit.